# Initializing and opening Jquery-ui dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

i'm trying to load a jquery-ui dialog when the page loaded .the page content is loading but the dialog doesn't show.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#loginfailed").dialog({
            width: 500, autoOpen: false, resizable: false, draggable: false,
            modal: false        
        });
        $("#loginfailed").dialog("open");
    });

</script>
```

am i missing something ? i almost read the doc but it doesn't help me much .

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code work fine!  Have you add `jquery-ui.js` in your `head` tag. Please see below with **div** id **loginfailed**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#loginfailed").dialog({
            width: 500, autoOpen: false, resizable: false, draggable: false,
            modal: false        
        });
        $("#loginfailed").dialog("open");   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="loginfailed">this is loading</div>
```